# Qt Widget - how to capture just a few keyboard keys

Tags: c++, qt4, keyboard

I know that with grabKeyboard() my widget is able to grab every keyboard event also if it's not focused, but what if I wanted to capture just three or four keys?

I tried with an event filter
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#installEventFilter

but that didn't work (perhaps because I installed it like this?)

```
 class MyWidget: public QGLWidget
    {
        ...
    protected:
        bool eventFilter( QObject *o, QEvent *e );
    };

    bool MyWidget::eventFilter( QObject *o, QEvent *e )
    {
        if ( e->type() == QEvent::KeyPress ) {
            // special processing for key press
            QKeyEvent *k = (QKeyEvent *)e;
            qDebug( "Ate key press %d", k->key() );
            return TRUE; // eat event
        } else {
            // standard event processing
            return FALSE;
        }
    }

// Installed it in the constructor
MyWidget::MyWidget()
{
    this->installEventFilter(this);
}
```

How can I intercept just a few keys in my widget and leave other widgets (QTextEdits) the rest?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your own comment says it all:

```
return TRUE; // eat event
```

As you return `true` for all keys, the event won't be further processed. You must return `false` for all keys you don't want to handle.

Another way without event filter but reimplementing keyPressEvent:

```
void MyWidget::keyPressEvent( QKeyEvent* event ) {
    switch ( event->key() ) {
    case Qt::Key_X:
        //act on 'X'
        break;
    case Qt::Key_Y:
        //act on 'Y'
        break;
    default:
        event->ignore();
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: The second way you wrote.. I did that! But somehow the "ignore" isn't forwarding the key to the other widgets and the grabKeyboard() keeps "eating" all the events, also the ones that are ignored

Comment: I solved with your help, now I "grabKeyboard()" just when the filter tells me that the openGL widget has the focus (i.e. the user has clicked on it) thank you!